# What Will Happen if PerformSelector is Fired While the Application is Asleep?

Tags: objective-c, macos, selector, delay, sleep

Does anyone know what will happen if I have a code,

```
[self performSelector:@selector(selectorFired) withObject:nil afterDelay:8];
```

And then i put the application to sleep using

```
sleep(9);
```

After sleeping, will my selector be called immediately? Or after sleeping, I'd have to wait 8 seconds before the selector is called? or since it's passed 8 seconds it won't be called anymore?

Comment: The application's timers are usually paused when the app leaves the foreground.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite: Timers can fire in the background when the app code is running. It just won't fire when app code is not running.

Comment: @newacct yes, but when an app leaves the foreground, it is *usually* (and by default) suspended, so the app's code is not running.

Comment: @BryanChen actually i tried it when I got home. the reason why I asked is because I needed to know and I couldn't try it right away. thanks. but i would appreciate it if you just ignore the question than put a comment like yours.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite & newacct thank you for the replies. I learned that it would fire immediately after the app resumes if its past the delay.

Comment: research are __required__ before ask question here. otherwise it can be downvoted and/or closed as "unclear what you're asking" or "too broad".

Comment: @BryanChen I believe it's clear and not too broad. If you want to downvote, that's fine but I think the question is clear and it can help other people who want to know about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `performSelector` with `afterDelay` parameter is followed by the `sleep` call on the same thread, the `performSelector` will obviously not fire until the app returns from `sleep` call, but because the `afterDelay` parameter (8 seconds) is shorter than the `sleep` duration (9 seconds), the `performSelector` will be called immediately after the thread finishes the `sleep`.

Comment: I experienced the same thing. Thank you so much!